# Any ways to have generic case classes or have a trait that specifies a copy method with a specific param?

Tags: scala, generics, copy

Hi so I have this use case where I have a function which takes a type which extends a trait. Let's say the trait a is:

```
trait A {
   val a: Double
}
```

Now I have multiple case classes that extend a.

```
case class B(val a: Double) extends A 
case class C(val a: Double, val b: Double) extends A
```

Now I want a generalized funtion such as:

```
def change[T <: A](newA: Double, state: T): T = {
   state.copy(a = newA)
}
```

If I can some how specify that the generic T is a case class that extends A, I can than infer that state has a clone method that has a param a. Or maybe there is a way to define a generic that says that there is a clone function that has exactly one param that is a.

Thanks

Comment: Only if you can implement `.clone(a: A)` in `A` as `T <: A` is the only type constraints/contract on type parameter `T` for `change`

Comment: that is nearly not a proper answer, but have you tried to look on monocle? It is a library specifically created for updating case classes in a programmer-friendly way.

Answer (score 1):

Building on a comment by [cchantep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3347384/cchantep), and on a [similar question I have asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779049/16673), following works:

```
trait A[T <: A[T]] {
  val a: Double
  def clone(a: Double = a): T
}

case class B(a: Double) extends A[B] {
  def clone(a: Double = a) = copy(a = a)
}

case class C(a: Double, b: Double) extends A[C] {
  def clone(a: Double = a) = copy(a = a)
}

def change[T <: A[T]](newA: Double, state: T): T = {
  state.clone(a = newA)
}
```

Is there any reason why do you want `change` to return the specific type and not just `A`? Without this requirement is could be a lot simpler, I have added the recursive type only to meet this requirement (to describe `clone` is always returning the original type):

```
trait A {
  val a: Double

  def clone(a: Double = a): A
}

case class B(a: Double) extends A {
  def clone(a: Double = a) = copy(a = a)
}

case class C(a: Double, b: Double) extends A {
  def clone(a: Double = a) = copy(a = a)
}

def change(newA: Double, state: A): A = {
  state.clone(a = newA)
}
```

Even with this simple implementation you could use `clone` directly instead of `change` and it would still keep the derived type statically. Still, I think such requirement makes little sense, and in the situations you compiler knows it is `B` or `C`, not `A`, you can use copy directly, you need `change` only when you have `A` only.