# Define common copy for a class hierarchy with many case classes

Tags: scala, clone, case-class

I would like to define a class hierarchy with about 100 `case classes` deriving from common base. The types are describing nodes in the AST hierarchy, like [this one](http://esprima.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax-tree-format.html). I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
trait Base {
  def doCopy: Base
}

trait CloneSelf[T <: CloneSelf[T]] extends Base {
  self: T =>

  def copy(): T
  override def doCopy: T = copy()
}


case class CaseA(a: String) extends Base with CloneSelf[CaseA]

case class CaseB(b: Int) extends Base with CloneSelf[CaseB]
```

This gives an error, because the existence of my `copy` prevents the `case classes` from defining the automatic copy. Is there some way how to implement the "clone" `doCopy` so that is uses the automatic `copy` of those `case classes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out defining the `doCopy` in each `case class` is actually less work than defining each class to inherit from `CloneSelf`. The code looks like this:

```
trait Base {
  def doCopy: Base
}

case class CaseA(a: String) extends Base {
  def doCopy = copy()
}

case class CaseB(b: Int) extends Base {
  def doCopy = copy()
}
```

I was surprised to learn that without explicit type on the overridden method the type is inferred by the compiler, therefore the static type of `CaseA("a").doCopy` is the same as of `CaseA("a").copy()`, i.e. `CaseA`, not `Base`. Adding explicit type for each `case class` would be probably more obvious, but this would require more work compared to just copy-pasting the same line into each of them. Not that it matters much - when I do copying via the `case class` type, I may use the `copy()` as well. It is only when I have the `Base` I need the `doCopy`, therefore declaring it like `def doCopy: Base = copy()` would do little harm.

Comment: You may want to consider naming your method `clone` and extending `scala.Cloneable` (which extends `java.lang.Cloneable`).

Comment: Right. I wanted this example to be simple, and overriding clone has its own peculiarities which I wanted to avoid here -  at least in Java, is this different in Scala?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's different. I'm just thinking that if I were a new developer on your team then I'd wonder how different `doCopy` is from `clone`.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to define a class hierarchy with about 100 case classes deriving from common base.

Please **do not** do that, you should absolutely find a pattern to avoid it! If you want to do this anyway... Try [ducktyping](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-duck-typing-in-scala-structural-types):

```
trait CloneSelf[T <: {def copy(): T}] {
  self: T  =>
    override def doCopy: T = copy()
}
```

I cannot test now so this probably won't compile, but you can figure it out by yourself with the general idea!

Edit:

Why having 100 subclasses is evil: imagine you perform one change in the base class, for instance change its name from `Base` to `BaseCloning` -> you'll have to change it in EVERY child class (100 changes).

How you will avoid that depends on what you want to do with your classes, check *creationnal* and *structural* patterns: factory, builder, prototype, flyweight, composite... Always think about "how much work will I have if I change something in the base class? Will it affect all children?"

Comment: Are there some common patterns how to design the hierarchy to avoid this, while still getting the automatic copy? (And could you elaborate what evil is in doing this?)

Comment: "imagine you perform one change in the base clase". I fail to see his reason, as I am using IDE or search and replace for this, therefore it does matter how many classes. Is there any serious reason why this is evil? Normal changes in the base class do not force me to change anything in the derived classes, as they just inherit the changes.

Comment: "you'll have to change it in EVERY child class" . . . or let your IDE do it for you.

Comment: Yes because I used a naming example so your IDE can do this for you. But he cannot perform business logic changes. It is very hard to explain as you don't want to explain what you'll end up doing with those classes. 
What if you add a second parameter type to `CloneSelf`, let's say, the type of the subclasse parameter?

Comment: I have added an explanation about the purpose - the types describe an AST (coming out of a parser).